# Finding a polynomial given some roots and its degree

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

> Find the $4^{th}$ degree polynomial function $f$ with real coefficients that has zeros $4$ (with multiplicity $2$) and $3 + 2i$.

I know that if you are given the imaginary solution of $3+2i$, then $3-2i$ has to be a solution. After using FOIL I got $13$. Where does this go then?

Comment: $(x - 4)^2 (x - 3 + 2i)(x- 3-2i)$

Comment: Note that its $(x-4)^2(x-(3-2i))(x-(3+2i))$.

Comment: Is this just the expanded version?

Comment: This is the factorised polynomial. If you have the roots of a polynomial then you can write the polynomial as a product of all its linear factors. If you want to expand it, use FOIL to multiply out the factors.

Comment: There are many such polynomials, all obtained by multiplying $(x-4)^2(x^2-6x+13)$ by a non-zero constant.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if a polynomial has the roots $r_1, r_2, ..., r_n$ (not necessarily distinct), your polynomial will be given by

$$f(x) = a(x - r_1)(x- r_2) ... (x-r_n)$$

for some constant $a \neq 0$.

When a root is said to have "multiplicity $m$," that just means that the root appears $m$ times in the set of roots (i.e. would have $m$ factors corresponding to it). As you correctly surmise, too, if a complex number $z$ is a root, so is its conjugate $\bar{z}$.

So, you know you have a polynomial with roots $4$ and $3+2i$, with the former of multiplicity $2$. The latter, being complex, means you have the root $3-2i$ too. Thus,

$$f(x) = a(x-4)(x-4)(x - (3+2i))(x - (3-2i))= a(x-4)^2 (x - (3+2i))(x - (3-2i))$$

---

At this point, typically, you're done. However, depending on the context, two restrictions may be imposed on the problem:

- You may only want real-valued coefficients *(this one applies in this case!)*
- You may want the more "standard" form of the polynomial as opposed to a factorization, i.e. may need to multiply it all out

The latter is trivial to address, if tedious. For the former, you can just multiply together the factors that have a complex number and its conjugate. In this case we see

$$(x - (3+2i))(x - (3-2i)) = x^2 - 6x + 13$$

As a general rule for future use, if $z = \alpha +i \beta$,

$$(x - z)(x - \bar{z}) = x^2 - x  \bar{z} - x z + z  \bar{z} = x^2 - x(z +  \bar{z}) + z \bar{z} = x^2 - 2 \alpha x + |z|^2$$

where $|z|=\sqrt{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}$ is the "modulus" or "magnitude" of $z$.

Thus, the form you would get in *this* scenario is

$$f(x) = a(x-4)^2(x^2 - 6x + 13)$$

and if you need to multiply it out, well, that's trivial enough.

---

Okay, but, well, what is $a$? $a$ is just a constant. You'll notice that, in the factored form, multiplying by a nonzero constant doesn't actually affect the roots of the polynomial, so we include that constant in order to account for *all* polynomials of the degree given (in your case, all polynomials of degree $4$ and those roots can be found per $f$ above).

We can't figure out what $a$ is, necessarily, without some sort of "initial values," such as points we know the polynomial goes through, among other things. If you just need a generic equation of the given form, you could leave $a$ in as an arbitrary constant, or pick particular values of $a$ (say $a=1$ or $a=4$ or whatever), depending on what the situation demands of you.